# Is there a way to get my LED to go up and down according to a potentiometer?

Tags: assembly, scroll, pic, led

So I just started to learn assembly language and got myself a micro controller [PIC18F4520](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/en010297) along with a 8x8 led-matrix. I've managed to turn an LED light on (yay!).
I've also managed to control the LED up and down column 0 based on if I press keypad SW0 or SW5..

I've seen a potentiometer on the side of my circuit. I would like to try it out, but I have no idea how it works. For the sake of simplicity I want to turn the potentiometer right and my LED light follows right etc. just like my code below, but instead of using the keypad... does it involve big changes to my code?

```
#include "p18F4520.inc"

    CONFIG OSC = HS
    CONFIG PWRT = OFF
    CONFIG WDT = OFF
    CONFIG PBADEN = OFF
    CONFIG LVP = OFF
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    org 0x000000
MAIN    CLRF    TRISD           ; make D output   
        CLRF    PORTB           ; make all row off
        BCF     TRISA,RA1       ; make port A output
        BSF     PORTA,RA1       ; turn on lights
        SETF    TRISB           ; set B to input



    VAR_A       EQU     0x000   ; access ram address 000 named as Var_A
    VAR_B       EQU     0x001   ; access ram address 001 named as Var_B
    VAR_C       EQU     0x002   ; access ram address 002 named as Var_C

        MOVLW   B'00000001'     ; init 1 LED
        MOVWF   VAR_A           ; move it into Var_A

LOOP        
        BTFSS   PORTB,RB5       ; check bit at RB5,skip next intruction if 1
        CALL    COMPARE         ; check RB5 and RB0
        BTFSS   PORTB,RB5       ; check bit at RB5,skip next intruction if 1
        CALL    ROTATE_RIGHT    ; rotate right
        BTFSS   PORTB,RB0       ; check bit at RB0,skip next intruction if 1
        CALL    ROTATE_LEFT     ; rotate left
        GOTO    LOOP        

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ROTATE_RIGHT    
        MOVF    VAR_A,W     ; move content in Var_A to Wreg
        MOVWF   PORTD       ; move to LED
        RRNCF   VAR_A       ; rotate right 0000001-1000000-01000000
        CALL    WAIT        ; delay
        return
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ROTATE_LEFT 
        MOVF    VAR_A,W     ; move content in Var_A to Wreg
        MOVWF   PORTD       ; move to LED
        RLNCF   VAR_A       ; rotate left 0000001-00000010-0000100
        CALL    WAIT        ; delay
        return
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WAIT    movlw   0xff        ; init 255 
        movwf   VAR_B       ; Var_B = 255
LOOP2   movlw   0xff        ; init 255
        movwf   VAR_C       ; Var_C 255
LOOP1   decfsz  VAR_C       ; decrement Var_C by 1
        goto    LOOP1       ; 
        decfsz  VAR_B       ; decrement Var_B by 1
        goto    LOOP2       ;
        return          
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------


;------------------------------------------------------------------------------

COMPARE BTFSS   PORTB,RB0
        GOTO    COMPARE
        return

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
        end
```

Comment: Potentiometers are variable resistors, so they are analogic components. You need to make a measurable signal depends on the potentiometer resistance (e.g. voltage divider) and sample it with the ADC facility of the uC. Nothing exoteric on PIC. If you have two-axis potentiometer you can even make a joystick :)